# How to classload Java EE 7 in Resin 4.0.42 and not use the Default Javaee-16.jar classloaded by default

Tags: jpa, classloader, java-ee-6, java-ee-7, resin

I am using the latest Spring framework 4.1.5 and Hibernate-Entity-Manager 4.3.8 along with Javax.Persistence-api 1.0.2 all with JPA 2.1.  This spec relies on Java EE 7.  I noticed that in Resin 4.0.42, it uses "javaee-16.jar".  The issue is I am getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()   
[Ljavax/persistence/Index; 
    at 
    org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:973) 
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:824) 
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3845) 


Method javax.persistence.Table.indexes() only exists in Java EE 7     
(Javax.Persistence-api 1.0.2) as a JPA 2.1 spec and NOT in Java EE 6 as a 
JPA  2.0 spec.
```

Problem is my code is based on JPA 2.1.  Is there anyway I can classload

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>javax</groupId> 
<artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId> 
<version>7.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

even after Resin has classloaded: javaee-16.jar first?

Answer (score 1):

Got it working where I load child libs first, not the other way around.  Resin was loading Parent-first.  I noticed others were having the same challenge with implementing JPA 2.1 on an app server that only implements JPA 2.0.  The key is that each app server has their own specific way to configure child libs (or your app's libs) first.

In my case, in Resin.xml, add the following:

```
<class-loader>
    <servlet-hack/>
</class-loader>
```

Comment: Hi , I tried but resin's amber(resin's JPA 1.0 implementation) complains `<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"> is an unexpected top-level tag` in persistence.xml . It is JPA 2.1's namespace. How did you get rid of it ? (resin 4.0.43)

Answer (score 0):

I has a similar error due to resin has jpa 2.0 and the app want jpa 2.1

fixed by added the lib to resin classpath in resin config file

```
<server-default>
   <jvm-classpath>path/to/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar</jvm-classpath>
   ....
<server-default>
```